# Keyboard does not open when clicking on UITextfield

Tags: swift, swift5

I create sign in page with swift programmatically coding. I tried simulator and device but keyboard did not opened when clicked on textfied.
when I write code in viewController with stroyboard, keyboard had opened. But, without using storyboard, keyboard is not opening.

Comment: What are you using then, SwiftUI? Add more information please.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the TextField's delegate? In the Storyboard you must have, but in code that is sometimes forgotten.

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let textField = UITextField()

    func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         textfield.delegate = self // Did you do this?
    }

}
```

Comment: If that didn't do the trick, you may need to tell it to `becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: I tried TextField delegate and becomeFirstResponder but didn't work

Answer (score -3):

If you are using simulator then you must go to I/O -> Keyboard -> Toggle software keyboard.

If you are using physical device then through code you need to set as as first responser as below:

```
textfieldName.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: Resign first responder closes the keyboard. That’s the inverse response